# How do you pass a component as a property?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am coming from React and in React, a lot of times you need to pass in another component as a property. For example, I am creating a modal LWC, and I need to be able to pass in whatever LWC I want inside of the modal.

Currently, I am using slot but styling it has been a nightmare. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building your own modal use the one from the [lwc recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/modal)

and then use it like so in the html of the lwc you are nesting the modal within

```
<c-modal header="Modal Header">
            <c-your-nested-lwc-name param1={param1}></c-your-nested-lwc-name>
            <div slot="footer">
                <lightning-button class="slds-m-right_small" label="Close" onclick={closeModal}></lightning-button>
                <lightning-button label="Save" variant="brand" onclick={save} disabled={disableButton}></lightning-button>
            </div>
    </c-modal>
```